# Как изменить стиль отображения индикатора (bootstrapv4), ширина почему то меняется автоматом на 20 пикселей вместо положенных 10ти, как решить?

Tags: css, bootstrap

```css
/**/
.carousel-indicators li{
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px !important;
}
/*--------------------------------------------*/
/* Нижняя карусель пользовательские настройки */
/* для внутренних компонентов <img> <h5> <p>  */
/*--------------------------------------------*/
.carousel_user {
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel_user img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #f7e327;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.carousel_user H5 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #282528;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 130px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.carousel_user p {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #646464;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Semibold';
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 146px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
/*--------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">


<!-- Карусель 2 начало -->
            <div  style="width: 229px;height: 402px;background-color: blue;">
            <div id="carousel_about" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel_about" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel_about" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel_about" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel_about" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner carousel_user">
                    <div class="carousel-item active" style="width: 229px ; height: 400px;">
                        <img class="d-block rounded-circle center-block" src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/man_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        <H5>Robert Leonaro</H5>
                        <p>CEO at CUBEDES</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item" style="width: 229px ; height: 400px;">
                        <img class="d-block rounded-circle" src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/man_2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                        <H5>Rober 2 eonaro</H5>
                        <p>CEO 2 CUBEDES</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item" style="width: 229px ; height: 400px;">
                        <img class="d-block rounded-circle" src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/wom_1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                        <H5>Rober 3 eonaro</H5>
                        <p>CEO 3 UBEDES</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item" style="width: 229px ; height: 400px;">
                        <img class="d-block rounded-circle" src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/wom_2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                        <H5>Rober 4 eonaro</H5>
                        <p>CEO 4 UBEDES</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
<!-- Карусель 2 конец -->
```

Comment: может из-за наличия flex ? уберите это или настройте, либо воспользуйтесь не каруселью и всё станет нормальным

Answer (score 0):

У вас для `.carousel-indicators li` прописано     `width: 10px !important;`,   замените на `flex:  0 1 10px;`, так как boostrap использует flex, который игнорирует  width.